# Eclipse plug-in CheckboxTreeViewer with multiple top-level elements?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, treeview, swt, jface

Does anyone know if there is a way to use a Eclipse TreeViewer (ContainerCheckedTreeViewer is the concrete implementation I'm using) where, instead of having a single top level element, there are multiple top level elements?

Currently I have a tree that looks something like this ...

- Root

  - Level 1

    - Level 1.1
    - Level 1.2
  - Level 2

    - Level 2.1
    - Level 2.2
  - Level 3

    - Level 3.1

But the root level isn't really useful for me ... what I really want is:

- Level 1

  - Level 1.1
  - Level 1.2
- Level 2

  - Level 2.1
  - Level 2.2
- Level 3

  - Level 3.1

I've seen the type of view I'm looking for in the preferences dialog and a few other places ... but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Just return an array of objects from your content provider `getElements` method.

Comment: @greg-449 I tried that already ... the first time `getText()` on my label provider is called, the parameter is the array list that the `getElements` method returned. I can't get the appropriate text from that object.

Comment: You have to arrange your data model so that the getElements works because that is the only way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, you gave me the hint I needed.  My starting point was an example that kind of hacked the root data element.  I reworked the code to properly set the input and the `getElements` method to return it's contents.